# Decir "Jugo de china"

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, españa, comida, hispanoamérica

Is "Jugo de china" common in Spain, or is it common in America?

Is it rather informal?

If it's used in Spain, is it rather "zumo de china"?

I didn't find in the dictionaries if it was informal, the regional uses, and if it's more used with jugo or zumo.

Comment: In Mexico I have only heard *jugo de naranja* although on product labels I have seen "zumo."  There is a small citrus fruit called "mandarina" (which does seem to have a connection with China).

Comment: In Mexico, there is a phrase China Poblana.  It's a dress, not a fruit.

Comment: what is the origin of "China poblana"?

Answer (score 7):

The use of the word *china* meaning *naranja* (*orange*) seems to be limited to some parts of Puerto Rico and Dominican Republic, according to [RAE's *Diccionario de americanismos*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=china). This meaning of the word *china* is not documented in the [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](https://dle.rae.es/china) (DLE, RAE).

In Spain, we do not use the word *china* with this meaning. We say *zumo de naranja* to refer to *orange juice*.

Comment: Thank you! So the word "china" is not understandable in Spain. And it's also informal?

Comment: @Quidam the word *china* is used in Spain meaning *female Chinese* [adjective or noun, not informal] , or *small stone* [not informal] or *small piece of hash(drug)* [slang] .

Comment: But is "china" as fruit informal in any country?

Comment: @Quidam that I cannot answer, as I am not from those countries. Hopefully someone else will know.

Comment: There are a lot of Argentine tango songs referencing a "china." Fortunately "jugo de china" is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely slang in Puerto Rico and the DR. I’ve heard fancy explanations as to why the call oranges “China”. I have my own theory. The orange juice box or the Tropicana brand has a cartoon iconic symbol of a Pacific Islander girl. Assuming her name is Ana, thus Tropic Ana. At some point I believe Puerto Ricans and or Dominicans living together in the states must have seen the cartoon trademark and believed it to be a Chinese female due to the eyes of the drawing and called the product “Hugo de China”

Comment: In English the term China orange was used for the sweet oranges when they were introduced https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/China_orange I imagine the sae may have happened in Spanish.